# Surjectivity counit of pushforward-pullback adjunction of an affine morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X \to Y$ be an affine morphism; is it true that the counit map

\begin{equation*} f^* f_* \mathcal{F} \to  \mathcal{F}
\end{equation*}
is surjective for every (coherent) sheaf $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: The counit of adjunction goes in the opposite direction.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake Sasha, I am going to correct right now; thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Since $f$ is affine, it is enough to check surjectivity after applying $f_*$. But the composition
$$ f_* F \to f_* f^* f_* F \to f_* F $$
of $f_*({\rm counit})$ with the unit of $f_* F$ is the identity (triangle identities).