# Unit map on étale site under $(f^*,f_*)$ adjunction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism between two irreducible schemes and $\mathcal{F}$ sheaf on the small étale site $Y_{ét}$. My question is more or less "dual" to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301369/surjectivity-counit-of-pushforward-pullback-adjunction-of-an-affine-morphism):

**Question:** Under which "reasonable" (=not too "exotic") assumptions do we know something about surjectivity or injectivity of the *unit* map under $(f^*,f_*)$ adjunction

$$ \mathcal{F} \to f_*f^*\mathcal{F}?\tag{$*$}\label{461816star}$$

If the question is too broad / unconcrete, let's pick the following "usual" conditions I'm principally interested in: It seems to be reasonable to ask for conditions posed on the level of the morphism $f$ (e.g., if $f$ is (open, closed) immersion, affine,.… etc + maybe something on the schemes $X$, $Y$ themselves) **(I)**
and on the level of the sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ (e.g., assuming it to be (étale) locally constant, locally free, etc.) **(II)**.

Clearly the question can be discussed on the level of stalks, so let $\overline{x}$ be a geometric point and $\mathcal{F}_{\overline{x}}= \varinjlim_{(U,u) \text{ étale nbhds of } x} \mathcal{F}(U)$ and
the question becomes if the stalk at $f_*f^*\mathcal{F} $ is going to be exhausted by this inductive system.

On assumptions of type **(I)**. I think that one can literally copy the proof for Zariski site to see that if $f$ is a closed immersion the unit map \eqref{461816star} is an isomorphism, for open immersion it is an isomorphism in points lying in the image, but not necessarily for points outside the image of $f$. Do we know more thinking in this direction?

What about the situation $X= \eta_Y$ the generic point of $Y$ and $f$ the canonical inclusion? Can we for example expect that \eqref{461816star} is an isomorphism if we require additionally something on $\mathcal{F}$, e.g., étale locally constant?

What about affineness of $f$ + again additional assumptions on $\mathcal{F}$, e.g., again étale locally constant?

It seems that the argument [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/301446) by Piotr Achinger for counit cannot be imitated because even though the composition $ f^*\mathcal{F} \to f^* f_* f^* \mathcal{F} \to f^* \mathcal{F} $ is the identity, we cannot "draw back" information about \eqref{461816star}, or am I missing something?

Comment: I made a [proofreading edit](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/461816/3) that seems to have somehow overwritten [your later edit](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/461816/4).  At least, the diff for the latter is empty, even though the revision message says that 74 characters changed.  I apologise; I didn't get any notification of any overwriting, so it must have been some sort of race condition when we submitted edits at almost the same time.

Comment: There are many equivalent ways to characterise when the unit is a monomorphim. For any adjunction, this is equivalent to $f^*$ being faithful, and for a geometric morphism of topoi $f \colon X \to Y$, you can for instance find more criteria in MacLane–Moerdijk's *Sheaves in geometry and logic*, Chapter VII, §4, Lemma 3 (where such a geometric morphism is called a *surjection*). For étale topoi of schemes, it's not so hard to see that this is equivalent to the morphism of schemes being surjective.

Comment: (Note that for a closed immersion, the *counit* is an isomorphism; the unit will only be surjective. Also, the sheaf $\mathscr F$ appears to live on $Y$, not on $X$.)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: Right. One aspect on the surjectivity of the unit $u:F \to i_*i^*F$ in case $i: X \subset Y$ closed immersion appears a bit mysterious. Even though it is known (eg [Milne's notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LEC.pdf) 8.3& 8.9 that for every $x =i(x)$ in the image we have that the stalk $(i_*i^*F)_x$ equals to $F_x$, I not see that the stalk map at $x$ - $u_x: F_x \to (i_*i^*F)_x =F_x$ *induced by the unit map*- is given by identity (what one "should" expect). Naively thinkng, even though these two stalks coinside, it seems not to be obvious that the induced map

Comment: by the unit on stalks in given exactly by the identity, even though this what one would intuitively expect to be plausible as at all the unit is adjoint to an identity map and the stalks are the same). Do you see an argument how see it?

Comment: Stalk means the pullback along $i_x \colon \{x\} \to Y$. But in fact it already becomes an isomorphism after pulling back along $i \colon X \to Y$: the map $i^*u \colon i^*\mathscr F \to i^*i_*i^* \mathscr F$ is inverse to the counit $i^*i_*i^* \mathscr F \to i^*\mathscr F$ of $i^*\mathscr F$ by the triangular identities.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: yes,I see, so using your notations the stalk map $u_x: \mathcal{F}_x \to (i_*i^* \mathcal{F})_x (=\mathcal{F}_x)$ induced from the unit map is nothing but the evaluation at $x$ of the left map of the composition  $i_x^* i^* \mathcal{F}  \xrightarrow{i_x^* i^*u}   i_x^* i^* i_* i^*\mathcal{F} \xrightarrow{i_x^* c} i_x^* i^* \mathcal{F} $ which is by functoriality identity on $i_x^* i^* \mathcal{F} $. Since counit $c$ and therefore it's pullback along $i_x$ is an iso, the left map is an iso too and we win.

Comment: But, the question is not only why $u_x$ is an iso -that's what your argument indeed shows - but even stronger, why $u_x$ is given as *identity map* on the stalks, (as tacitly claimed in the diagram on p 62, prf of Prop 8.5)

Comment: By the way:  why for $i$ closed immersion the counit is even an iso?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: a little update: the question in last comment about why counit is an iso for closed immersion is resolved now: it even holds more generally for immersions. But in order to connect this to the question in the penultimate comment and the argument you used above: is it even true that in setting above the counit on level of stalks is even given as identity map and not just "certain" iso?

Comment: It doesn't strictly speaking make sense to say that the counit on stalks is an identity, because the two sides are not literally the same set. They become canonically identified via this morphism. This isomorphism is apparently so natural to Milne that he considers it an identity by abuse of language. This is not an unusual thing to do in category theory, especially in constructions like pullback of a sheaf that are defined by universal properties, so only well-defined up to a unique isomorphism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two observations:

(1) This unit is injective if $f$ is set-theoretically surjective: For the image of a section nonvanishing at a point $x$ to vanish, the associated section of $f^* \mathcal F$ on the inverse image open set would have to vanish, so it would vanish at every point, including the inverse image of that point, which is impossible.

(2) This unit is surjective if $f$ is proper with geometrically connected fibers: Proper base change lets us reduce to the case where the base is a geometric point, in which case $\mathcal F$ must be a constant sheaf, and then this is the computation of the global sections of the constant sheaf on connected spaces. This generalizes the closed immersion case you mention.

Comment: on point (2): to be sure, you are refering to the version of "proper base change thm" as given in Thm 17.10 in [Milne's LEC](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LEC.pdf), applying it to $f^* \mathcal{F}$ (because Milne's $\mathcal{F}$ lives on domain, "my" on base/codomain ) and assuming it to be constructible (...a relative "natural" assumption)?

Comment: about point (1) I not pretty sure why in case $f$ set-theoretically surjective, the unit map is injective only, but not surjective too. I'm working with $f^*$ to be etale sheafification of the presheaf on page 60, after Prop. 8.6 in Milne's notes. Let $\overline{y} \to Y$ a geom pt, and we want to check that unit map is surj too, assuming it's set-theor image the image of $f$. If I not make any mistake then we only have to check that the inductive system of etale nbhoods's $U$ of $y$ under which the stalk $\mathcal{F}_y$ is formed as inductive limit, is *cofinal* in the inductive system

Comment: determining the stalk at $\overline{y}$ of $f_*f^*\mathcal{F}$. But the inductive system of the latter consists of etale maps $V \to Y$ with the proprty that there *exist* an etale nbhood $U \to Y$ of $y$ such that the composition $U \times_Y X \to X \to Y$ factors through $V$, see p 60. Thats stalk of the presheaf but it coincide with stalk of assoc sheaf. But if the image of geom pt $\overline{y}$ lies as set theor pt $y$ in image of $f$, then seemingly the inductive system of the etale nbhoods of $y$ is cofinal in the inductive system of the stalk of $ f_*f^*\mathcal{F}$ at $y$, doesn't it?

Comment: Indeed, if $V \to Y$ as above, then is contains $y$, so is an etale nbhood of $y$, and therefore it's a member of inductive system defining the stalk $ \mathcal{F}_y$, right? So this would imply that unit map at $y$ is surjective too, as long $y$ (more precisely "the set theor image" of geo pt $\overline{y} \to Y$ lies in the set theor of $f$. Or do I missing an important point? Do you maybe see where I'm making an error in my resonings, such that the unit map for surjective $f$ stays only injective as you stated in (1), but not neccessarily surjective, as I tried prove - but maybe

Comment: have overlooked something?

Comment: @user267839 (2) Yes, probably I am missing a constructibility assumption. (1) If $Y$ is a single point and $X$ is two points then the unit map is not surjective. I think the problem in your argument is missing the sheafification step for $f^* \mathcal F$. The sheafification step is not necessary when computing stalks of $f^* \mathcal F$ but is when computing stalks of $f_* f^* \mathcal F$.

Comment: oh thanks, I see the problem with my "argument". However I'm not completely persuaded by the argument on injectivity of the unit in (1). It looks like something working in realm of naive varieties where no nonreduced/ nilpotent phenomena occure. There of course a surjection on level of sets implies injectivity for assoc maps of sections. But what if we dealing with eg nonzero nilpotent sections, and we want to see that it's image under unit map is nonzero too? Is it possible to modify your argument in (1) to capture such kind of issues or does it already cover such phenomena?

Comment: More precisely, I understood your phrase "image of a section nonvanishing at a point $x$" as that you start with a section $s \in F(U)$ with $s(x) \neq 0$ in $F_x \otimes_{O_{Y,x}} \kappa(x)$ and show that its image in $f^*F(f^{-1}(U))$ isn't zero. But what if we start with nilpotent nonzero section in the sense that $s(x)=0$ in all geom pts of $U$? Does the arguemnt in (1) capture issues like this too?

Comment: @user267839 Nonreduced and nilpotence phenomena are irrelevant for the étale site, and only appear when you work with sheaves of rings or sheaves of modules. Every nonzero section has a nonzero stalk at some geometric point.

Comment: right sorry, so on that level the expression $F_x \otimes_{O_{Y,x}} \kappa(x)$ as "evaluation of $F$ at $x$" already even from structural reasons not make any sense as $F$ above is regarded only as sheaf in sets /groups. So in (1) you meant by "section nonvanishing at a point $x$" exactly that this $s \in F(U)$ just not vanishes at the stalk $F_x$, right? Ok, geometrically/ intuitively the argument in (1) is plausible now but I'm not sure how to fill following gap:

Comment: As far as understand you correctly your argument
can be formalized as follows: Assume $s \in F(U)$ not
vanishes in $F_x$ for certain $x \to Y$, therefore it's image 
$s_x \in F_x$ under canonical localization map 
$F(U) \to F_x$ is non zero as assumed. 

Now the the unit map over $U$ is given as composition
$u: F(U) \to f^{\dagger}F(f^{-1}(U)) \to f^*F(f^{-1}(U)) $ where $f^{\dagger}F$ is the inverse presheaf in sense of Milne's notes on p 60, and second map is the sheafification.

Comment: Let $x' \to X$ be any point lying over $x=f(x')$ 
(here I abuse strictly speaking some nototion), which
by assumption exists. Let $f^*s =u(s)$ be the image of $s$
under the unit map and $(f^*s)_{x'}$ it's image 
under can localization 
$f^*F(f^{-1}(U)) \to (f^*F)_{x'} $. Now so far I understand 
the argument in (1) formally it implicitly uses the 
fact that $(f^*F)_{x'} \cong F_x$ (Milne, Rmk 8.9), so we can
identify $(f^*s)_{x'} = s_x \neq 0$ and so $f^*s \neq 0$ 
and we win.

Comment: But what I still not understand, why the isomorphism 
$(f^*F)_{x'} \cong F_x$ on stalks is *induced* by the 
unit map? Naively thinking, it's always possible to have 
two objects $A,B$ beeing abstractly isomorphic (ie there *exist* an iso between them), but nevertheless 
there might exist also nonisomorphic maps $A \to B$. 

But why here this is not the case, ie that precisely the map
$F_x \to (f^*F)_{x'}$ *which is induced from the unit* is an iso?

Comment: To put it in the nutshell my concern reduces to: Why the well known identification $(f^*F)_{x'} \cong F_x$ - which so far I understand the argument in (1) correctly is implicitly exploited there - is precisely induced from the unit map?

Comment: @user267839 The unit of the adjunction is the map $ \mathcal F \to f_* f^* \mathcal F$ induced by the adjunction isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal F, f_* f^* \mathcal F) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(f^* \mathcal F,  f^* \mathcal F) $ applied to the identity of $f_* \mathcal F$. So one just has to use the construction of the adjunction isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(f^*A,  B) \to \operatorname{Hom}(A, f_* B) $

Comment: i.e. given a map $f^* A \to B$ and a section of $A$ over some open set $U$, we obtain a section of $f^* A $ over $f^{-1}(U)$, and then applying the map we obtain a section of $B$ over $f^{-1}(U)$, which by definition gives a section of $f_* B$ over $U$. Taking $A = \mathcal F$ and $B = f^* \mathcal F$ we can track what this does on stalks. But maybe it's easier to argue directly from this: The induced map $A(U) \to f_* B(U)$ is a composition of three maps $A(U) \to f^* A ( f^{-1}(U)) \to B( f^{-1}(U) ) \to f_* B(U)$.

Comment: The third map is an isomorphism by definition. The second map is an isomorphism if $A = \mathcal F$ and $B = f^* \mathcal F$ and the map $f^* A \to B$ we are using is the identity (since the identity is an isomorphism). So the composition is injective iff $A (U) \to f^* A( f^{-1} (U))$ is injective.  But this we can check on stalks using the definition of pullback.

Comment: Sure, injectivity of $A (U) \to f^* A( f^{-1} (U))$ is the interesting part for which as you said it suffice to check it on stalks. Here an idea: As stalks of presheaf and it's sheafification coinside, we can decompose this map even once more to $A (U) \to f^{\dagger} A( f^{-1} (U)) \to f^* A( f^{-1} (U))$ where $f^{\dagger} A$ is the presheaf as in Milne's notes at p 60. So it even suffice to show that the first map is injective. Let $s \in A(U)$ nonzero and $f^*s$ writen suggestively it's image in $f^{\dagger} A( f^{-1} (U)) $. Let $x \to Y$ a geom point with $s_x \neq 0$ at stalk $A_x$.

Comment: If I'm not missing something then the crucial observation is that the canon map $A(U) \to A_x$ to the stalk factors *naturally* through $ f^{\dagger} A( f^{-1} (U)) $ as the latter is by construction a limit over certain neighbhd's of $x$. Furthermore the stalk of $ f^{\dagger} A$ at any arbitrary $x' \to X$ lying over $x$ is - if l'm not missing something - identified with stalk $A_x$ *naturally* as a set, ie no "identifications" involved, but a honest equality.

Comment: So the map  $A_x \to (f^{\dagger} A)_{x'} $ on stalks *"prolonging the unit map* $A (U) \to f^{\dagger} A( f^{-1} (U)) $ naturally (in the sense of natural commutativity) is literally the identity map und we win. Is the consideration correct?

Comment: @user267839 That all sounds right to me.